# Add setStragy to VectorSource

Tags: constructor, prototype, openlayers, super

I use openlayers js library version 6.15.1

I have a class that inherits VectorSource. I don't know what to do in my constructor cause I would like my own stategy. I can't call super({ strategy: this._myStrategy, ... }) so how to do it?

Can I add the function setStrategy in VectorSource prototype? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Please provide a snippet of your code so that we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the `this` for the custom strategy function inside another function which is valid in `super`

```
class CustomVectorSource extends VectorSource {
  constructor(options) {
    options = options || {};
    const strategy = options.strategy;
    options.strategy = function (extent, resolution) {
      if (typeof this.customStrategy_ !== 'function') {
        return [];
      }
      return this.customStrategy_(extent, resolution);
    };
    super(options);
    this.customStrategy_ = strategy;
  }
  setStrategy(strategy) {
    this.customStrategy_ = strategy;
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-wfs-forked-08vw80?file=/main.js